# Eclipse Android SDK Manager Warning: null

Tags: xml, eclipse, android

I don't really know anything about this, but I'm learning how to write Android apps.  I'm working through the [Hello, World | Android Developer Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html), and was doing fine until I tried the XML code.  I copy/pasted the code given in the tutorial into the layout file as instructed.  But when I attempted the next step (open strings.xml from res/values), I encountered problems:  java.lang.NullPointerException.  In the Console below, I can see several instances of "SDK Manager warning: null".

Does anyone know how I can fix this?  Obviously, it's some problem with the SDK but I don't know what/where to check.

In the error log (several instances of this error):
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.ElementImpl.getDefaultValue(ElementImpl.java:259)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.ElementImpl.getAttributeNS(ElementImpl.java:329)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.uimodel.UiElementNode.getShortDescription(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.ui.tree.UiModelTreeLabelProvider.getText(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.WrappedViewerLabelProvider.getText(WrappedViewerLabelProvider.java:108)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.WrappedViewerLabelProvider.update(WrappedViewerLabelProvider.java:164)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:152)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:934)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:102)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1014)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:481)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2141)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createTreeItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:829)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$1.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:804)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:778)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:749)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1492)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(TreeViewer.java:833)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$5.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1476)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1422)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.preservingSelection(TreeViewer.java:403)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1383)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1469)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:274)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1664)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.ui.tree.UiTreeBlock.createTreeViewer(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.ui.tree.UiTreeBlock.createMasterPart(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.forms.MasterDetailsBlock.createContent(MasterDetailsBlock.java:161)
at org.eclipse.ui.forms.MasterDetailsBlock.createContent(MasterDetailsBlock.java:142)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.resources.ResourcesTreePage.createFormContent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormPage$1.run(FormPage.java:152)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormPage.createPartControl(FormPage.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.pageChange(FormEditor.java:471)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidEditor.pageChange(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.setActivePage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1067)
at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.setActivePage(FormEditor.java:603)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidEditor.selectDefaultPage(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidEditor.addPages(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages(FormEditor.java:138)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2863)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2768)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2760)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2711)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2707)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2691)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2682)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:651)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:610)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:208)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:274)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:250)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.OpenAndExpand.run(OpenAndExpand.java:49)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:221)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$3.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:185)
at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:845)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:843)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1131)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:462)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1235)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:264)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:258)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:298)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2629)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2593)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2427)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:670)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:663)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Linziza

Comment: so it's having issues with the plugin: org.eclipse.jface.  I found the plugin but now what do I do?  How do I make it accessible to my program?

Answer (score 0):

Try to close eclipse and reopen it. The exception generated is an eclipse exception.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried closing & restarting Eclipse but I'm still getting the error.  It says java.lang.NullPointerException so it's trying to get something that isn't there?  So, what is it looking for?  I thought it might be the SDK plugin or something but everything seems to be installed properly (according to the tutorial).  Is there something else I can check?  I don't know how to get around this.... thanx L

Comment: Well it only happens when you are editing that xml file right, and the exception is an Eclipse generated exception so it doesn't have anything to do with the SDK it doesn't appear. Are you running the latest version that just released a few days ago? It could be buggy.